# Flask SocketIO client events acting weird

Tags: flask, events, socket.io, client

I'm very new to flask (and French so sory for the frensh comments ut i didn't want to alter my code).

I am creating a flask voting app for one of my school event and I'm having issues with the Flask SocketIO client events. More specifically, only 1/3 is working at all.
this code is made for the page that will be displayed on big screens in the room and shows the number of votes for a performance and the number of people connected currently to the website.

The client code is the following:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.1.3/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Connexion au namespace /viewer
            var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/viewer');

            // Gestionnaire d'événement pour la connexion
            socket.on('connect', function () {
                console.log('Connected to server');
            });

            // Gestionnaire d'événement pour la déconnexion
            socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                console.log('Disconnected from server');
            });

            // Écoute de l'événement 'votes_count' dans le namespace /viewer
            socket.on('update_viewer', function(data) {
                // Mise à jour de l'affichage avec le nombre de votes et de personnes connectées
                console.log('Received data:', data);
                if (data != null) {
                    document.getElementById('votes-count').innerText = data.count;
                    document.getElementById('connected-users').innerText = data.connected_users;
                }

            });
        </script>
```

The issue is that after trying to debug it for a while, the only thing that is displayed in my brower console is “Disconnected from server” when I reboot the flask server.

Also, the server logs indicate that the connection process is happening normally :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2024 00:16:02] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OrczJJ2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
zAKCXGNyUlcMJb-4AAAA: Received packet MESSAGE data 0/viewer,
zAKCXGNyUlcMJb-4AAAA: Sending packet MESSAGE data 4/viewer,"Unable to connect"
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2024 00:16:02] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OrczJO0&sid=zAKCXGNyUlcMJb-4AAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
zAKCXGNyUlcMJb-4AAAA: Received request to upgrade to websocket
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2024 00:16:02] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OrczJO1&sid=zAKCXGNyUlcMJb-4AAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2024 00:16:03] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OrczJSr&sid=zAKCXGNyUlcMJb-4AAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
zAKCXGNyUlcMJb-4AAAA: Upgrade to websocket successful
zAKCXGNyUlcMJb-4AAAA: Sending packet PING data None
zAKCXGNyUlcMJb-4AAAA: Received packet PONG data 

multiple pings successful after that...
```

The big problem is that I am unable to trigger the update_viewer, essential for this app. But I think that the problem is linked to the fact that the connect event is not working as well.

So, why is the 'connect' event not working as it should ?
I have have checked multiple sources and i can't find where my code is wrong